# Quantization in analog systems

Tags: java

The value of 1.25, How can I get the correct value in the array I created and print this value on the screen?

```
static final String[] DIGITS = {
    "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111"
};

for example 0.00 - 1.25 => 0000, 1.25 - 2.50=> 0001 8.75-10.0 => 0111
```

Comment: Is the range 1-9? And would the values be mapped by proximity, e.g. 1.49 = 0000 but 1.5 = 0001?

Comment: Can you explain how you get this mapping: 8.76 => 0111? Your array has in total 8 elements with indexes from 0 to 7. Why for this number 8.76 have you chosen the last element of the array?

Comment: sample output sequence for a table in the lesson

Comment: looks like you want the number divided by 1.25 to get the array index - but the values `1.25`, `2.50` .. are not clear, by given explanation can be mapped to 2 values

Answer (score 1):

It seems that every interval with length of 1.25 is mapped to one element of your array. You can calculate the index by dividing the provided value by 1.25 then.

```java
int index = (int)(value / 1.25);
if (index < 0) {
    index = 0;
}
if (index > DIGITS.length - 1) {
    index = DIGITS.length - 1;
}
System.out.println(value + " => " + DIGITS[index]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example "0.00 - 1.25 => 0000, 1.25 - 2.50=> 0001 8.75-10.0 => 0111" indicates you have a range [0.0, 10.0]. To get a mapping for an array of any length, you could do the following:

```
double value = ... //get it from somewhere
//clamp to range in case the value doesn't match
value = Math.max(0.0, Math.min(10.0, value));

double step = 10.0 / array.length; //in your case that should be 1.25 (or very close to that)
//the Math.min(..., array.length - 1) is needed because 10.0/step could result in "array.length"
int index = Math.min((int) (value / step), array.length - 1);
var element = array[index];
```

In your case this would map [0.0,1.25[ (so values >= 0.0 and < 1.25) to 0, [1.25,2.5[ to 1 etc. 
As the comment says 10.0 would be mapped to 8 which is an illegal index so we need to handle that special case.

In more general terms you could map values of a range `[a,b]` to array indices the following way:

```
double value = ... //get it from somewhere
value = Math.max(a, Math.min(b, value));

//b - a is the size of the range
double step = (b-a) / array.length;

//value - a to "move" the value into a range of the same size but starting at 0
int index = Math.min((int) ((value-a) / step), array.length - 1);
var element = array[index];
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure how you want the binary strings to decode into analogue values. If the quantisation levels are equally spaced, you can divide by the spacing and use [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-).